# Can I use ANSI SQL for graph data in AgensGraph?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, agens-graph

I know AgensGraph supports ANSI SQL and Cypher language both.
If so, can I use ANSI SQL for graph data? and the opposite too.

What I want to know is, should I choose and use the language for each data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agensgraph doesn't appear to explicitly say you can't use SQL on graphs or Cypher on tables, but if you look at their [architecture](https://bitnine.net/documentations/operation-manual-en.html#architecture), the relational and graph databases are almost completely separate, only sharing the transaction/cache layers.

So only Cypher can access graphs, and only ANSI SQL can access tables; So the only way to cross reference both is to use the hybrid format.

Further reading: [Docs](https://bitnine.net/documentation/)